# How do I replace a backslash and newline character in sequence using regular expressions in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

Say I have a file of text where lines have been wrapped deliberately. Each wrapped line ends with a backslash character '\' and then a newline. Example:

```
foo.bar=blah,blah,blah,bl\
ah,blah
foo2.bar=blah,blah,blah,b\
lah,blah
```

I want to unwrap those lines so that it becomes:

```
foo.bar=blah,blah,blah,blah,blah
foo2.bar=blah,blah,blah,blah,blah
```

Currently when I attempt to do this using the following command I get no matches and thus no changes:

```
( Get-Content .\somefile.txt | Out-String ) -replace '\\\n',''
```

If I use either '\' or '\n' it replaces either the backslash or the newline, but when used together it produces no matches.

Comment: `-replace "\\\n", ""` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a Windows style line ending, then it's a carriage return and a linefeed, so `0xD0XA` or `\r\n`. If you want to handle both possibilities:

```
-replace '\\\r?\n',''
```

So basically, the backslash `\\` followed by an optional carriage return `\r?` followed by a linefeed `\n`.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks so much! This has been driving me crazy this afternoon.